# Bash script No such file or directory - evaluate $HOME in variable

Tags: bash

When paths like `$HOME/myfile` are read into a variable, it's not evaluated by commands like `cat` or `md5sum`. They show `'$HOME/myfile': No such file or directory`.

Say we read paths from a file like:

```
$HOME/file1 
$HOME/file2
```

and load each line into a variable `path`. Next I want to evaluate the checksum of each file. The Whole script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cat paths | while read line;
do
   hash1=$(md5sum $line)
   echo $hash1
done
```

where I get: *md5sum '$HOME/file1': No such file or directory*

I'm guessing that the key are those single quotes - path is evaluated to `$HOME`, it's taken as a dead string. How to make it alive?

Comment: You could solve it with `$(eval md5sum $line)`, but eval comes with its own problems. The best solution would be to not use environment variables in your file, if you can control it. If you are guaranteed that it's just paths that start with `$HOME` and no other variables are present, you can specially replace them with the full path.

Comment: `cat paths | envsubst '$HOME' | while read line`

Comment: `$line` and `$hash1` should be quoted ( `"$line"`, `"$hash1"` ) to avoid corruption

Comment: @jhnc Why cat instead of redirection?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy minimal change to make the variable expansion work (although it's not really "minimal", I guess). redirection would obviously avoid the "useless use of cat"

Answer (score 3):

When you read text into a variable, it is just text. The various substitution mechanisms that the shell supports are applied to shell script source code, not to data. (Imagine the consequences if you had to guard every literal backtick or dollar sign in text files you wanted to process.)

Notice that it's the shell itself, not individual commands like `cat` or `md5sum`, which performs these expansions. That's how the behavior is consistent and predictable across utilities (unlike e.g. on Windows, which is one of the many reasons it's a more frustrating platform for developers).

There is always `eval`, of course; but as its name suggests, `eval` is evil.

You could simply expand any substitution mechanisms you want to support as part of your code.

```
sed -e "s%\\\$HOME/%$HOME/%" \
    -e "s%~/%$HOME/%" \
    -e "s%\\\$HOME\$%$HOME%" \
    -e "s%^~\$%$HOME%" paths | 
while read -r line
do
   md5sum "$line"
done
```

Notice the use of `read -r`, the [proper use of quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable), the avoidance of a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo). The site https://shellcheck.net/ can warn for common beginner mistakes like these; please run it before asking for human assistance. When your script contains many basic errors, the answers tend to get bulky and distracted, and sometimes the beginner mistake is the reason you get an error.

Comment: I wonder if single quotes -- as in ```sed -e 's%\$HOME/%'"$HOME"'/%' -e 's%~/%'"$HOME"'/%' -e 's%\$HOME$%'"$HOME"'%' -e 's%^~$%'"$HOME"'%'``` -- make this easier or harder to read; less backslashes needed, but more needing to switch between quoting contexts

Comment: Yeah, I meant to comment on the rather wretched backslashitis required by the double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

> How to make it alive?

Looks like ideal case for envsubst.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=$(envsubst '$HOME' <<<"$line")
    echo "$line"
done < paths
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Overall:

```
envsubst '$HOME' <paths | xargs -d'\n' md5sum
# or just:
envsubst <paths | xargs -d'\n' md5sum
```